# Best way to measure elapsed time in Scheme

Tags: time, scheme, chicken-scheme

I have some kind of "main loop" using glut. I'd like to be able to measure how much time it takes to render a frame. The time used to render a frame might be used for other calculations. The use of the function `time` isn't adequate.

```
(time (procedure))
```

I found out that there is a function called `current-time`. I had to import some package to get it.

```
(define ct (current-time))
```

Which define ct as a `time` object. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any arithmetic packages for dates in scheme. I saw that in Racket there is something called `current-inexact-milliseconds` which is exactly what I'm looking for because it has nanoseconds.

Using the time object, there is a way to convert it to nanoseconds using

```
(time->nanoseconds ct)
```

This lets me do something like this

```
(let ((newTime (current-time)))
   (block)
   (print (- (time->nanoseconds newTime) (time->nanoseconds oldTime)))
   (set! oldTime newTime))
```

Seems good enough for me except that for some reasons it was printing things like this

```
0
10000
0
0
10000
0
10000
```

I'm rendering things using opengl and I find it hard to believe that some rendering loop are taking 0 nanoseconds. And that each loop is quite **stable** enough to always take the same amount of nanoseconds.

Comment: Sounds like your `current-time` has a granularity of 10 microseconds. You might want to measure a bigger batch of work, e.g., 1000 iterations, then divide the resulting time by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

After all, your results are not so surprising because we have to consider the limited timer resolution for each system. In fact, there are some limits that depend in general by the processor and by the OS processes. These are not able to count in an accurate manner than we expect, despite a quartz oscillator can reach and exceed a period of a nanosecond. You are also limited by the accuracy and resolution of the functions you used. I had a look at the documentation of Chicken scheme but there is nothing similar to (current-inexact-milliseconds) → real? of Racket.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the `current-inextact-milliseconds` in my scheme. (Chicken scheme) It's unclear where to get it.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I came with the solution that I should write it in C and bind it to scheme using bindings.

```
(require-extension bind)

(bind-rename "getTime" "current-microseconds")

(bind* #<<EOF
uint64_t getTime();

#ifndef CHICKEN
#include <sys/time.h>
uint64_t getTime() {
    struct timeval tim;
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    return 1000000 * tim.tv_sec + tim.tv_usec;
}
#endif

EOF
)
```

Unfortunately this solution isn't the best because it will be chicken-scheme only. It could be implemented as a library but a library to wrap only one function that doesn't exists on any other scheme doesn't make sense.

Since nanoseconds doens't actually make much sense after all, I got the microseconds instead.

Watch the trick here, define the function to get wrapped above and prevent the include to get parsed by `bind`. When the file will get loaded in Gcc, it will build with the include and function definition.

Answer (score 0):

CHICKEN has current-milliseconds: http://api.call-cc.org/doc/library/current-milliseconds